# Jsoup select text after tag with many tag

Tags: java, jsoup, extract

I want to extract a text after each text using [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Is there any way to select it?

Example code like below:

```
<div class="content">
<div name="panel-summary" id="summary">
    <p>
    <strong>A: </strong>*thank you* **I want to retrieve this text**<br>
    <strong>B: </strong>*Bla..bla* *I don't want this text*<br>
    <strong>C: </strong>*what ever text* *I dont want this*                         
        <strong>D: </strong>*anythinh text* *I want this*<br>
        <strong>E: </strong>*Bla..bla* *I don't want this text*t<br>
        <strong>F: </strong>*anythinh text* *I want this*<br>
    </p>

    <p>I want this</p>
```

and when it finish it creates auto id example id=123

Comment: What you need to think about is what the things you want to get have in common. Do you always want the 1st, 4th, 6th element? Does the `<strong>` tag have  to contain A D or F? Etc..

Comment: @Mark.. I just want text after tag example: <strong>A: </strong>Thank you<br>.. I just want text "thank you" not "A" in tag..

Comment: But why do you only want the text after the 1st one and not the 2nd one?

Comment: @Mark .. Because I just want a content not the title..

Comment: Your explanation contradicts what you posted in question. You claim that you want text after tag like `<strong>A: </strong>Thank you<br>` should result in "thank you" without "A". But why in `<strong>B: </strong>I dont want<br>` there is `I dont want`? Shouldn't this also be part of expected result according to that rule? What *another* rule/logic are you using to recognize that you don't want this? How do you differ/recognize what you want from what you don't want?

Comment: @Pshemo.. Yes I want text after tag.. but not all text after tag I want just some of them.. that why I put   I want this and I don't want this..

Comment: @Pshemo.. I had edited my question

Comment: How do you decide what you want and what you don't? Is it always guaranteed to be six `<strong>XX</strong>YY<br>`? If yes do you always want content from only 1st, 4th and 6th?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you just want the text after `A:`, `D: `, and `F: ` like in your example? And why don't you want the text after `B: `, `C: `, and `E: `? What are your criteria?

Comment: Yes exactly.. I always want content from only 1st, 4th and 6th..

Comment: BTW that is precisely what Mark asked you about in first comment :)

Comment: Sorry..  I missunderstood..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that all `<strong>` elements which you want to find will always contain `A:` or `D:` or `F:` then with `strong:matchesOwn(regex)` (where regex will represent `A:|D:|F:`) we can select those elements.

After handling `strong` we can move on to second `<p>` and get its textual content via `text()`.

```
String html = "<div class=\"content\">\n" +
        "<div name=\"panel-summary\" id=\"summary\">\n" +
        "    <p>\n" +
        "    <strong>A: </strong>*thank you* **I want to retrieve this text**<br>\n" +
        "    <strong>B: </strong>*Bla..bla* *I don't want this text*<br>\n" +
        "    <strong>C: </strong>*what ever text* *I dont want this*                         \n" +
        "        <strong>D: </strong>*anythinh text* *I want this*<br>\n" +
        "        <strong>E: </strong>*Bla..bla* *I don't want this text*t<br>\n" +
        "        <strong>F: </strong>*anythinh text* *I want this*<br>\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <p>I want this</p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements pElements = doc.select("#summary p");
Elements strongElements = pElements.first().select("strong:matchesOwn(A:|D:|F:)");
for (Element strong : strongElements) {
    System.out.println(strong.nextSibling());//get next element, including textual element
}
System.out.println("---");
System.out.println(pElements.get(1).text());//textual content of <p>I want this</p>
```

Output:

```
*thank you* **I want to retrieve this text**
*anythinh text* *I want this*
*anythinh text* *I want this*
---
I want this
```

---

If you don't want to rely on content of `<strong>` but simply on its indexes then pick all of them like

```
Elements allStrElemens = doc.select("#summary p strong");
```

and simply pick ones you needed via their indexes (remember that indexes start from 0) like

```
System.out.println(allStrElemens.get(0).nextSibling());
System.out.println(allStrElemens.get(3).nextSibling());
System.out.println(allStrElemens.get(5).nextSibling());
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "auto generate id".